# How to make a Panel Control of cookies?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to create a cookie control panel in php or some system with which I can grant the user the possibility of disabling cookies such as those of social networks, thirds. I have seen some sites that allow you to distinguish between technical cookies and others which can be dispensed with.
I can't find anything about it or I can't find it because of my lack of knowledge about it. Can somebody help me.

Currently I only generate the cookie notice and I treat them but I can't think of how to allow the user to cancel twitter cookies for example.

Comment: you can only control the cookies you created (associated with your domain). If you want, for example, to prevent twitter cookies, you just need to not load twitter into your page (feed, ressources,...)

Comment: and cookies like a _ga ?

Comment: @ismaelOcaña For that specific case, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-opt-out.

Comment: But if it's GMaps that is used in one of the pages of my site, I could do it that way or I could only do it by removing it.